# Saving Screenshot of the web page that has Cesium

Tags: screenshot, cesiumjs

I'm trying to add a button to my interface that will download a screenshot taken of the web page. 
It works for the side bar but my Cesium map appears plain white.

Can someone help me out with is?

[Here is a code](https://plnkr.co/edit/O4JSjoc37Ma2ELVlzS8a?p=preview)

```
var Capture = function() {
html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var tempcanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
        tempcanvas.width=1050;
        tempcanvas.height=1050;
        var context=tempcanvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(canvas,5,5);
        var link=document.createElement("a");
        link.href=tempcanvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');   //function blocks CORS
        link.download = 'screenshot.jpg';
        link.click();
    }
});
```

}

This was based on the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828187/how-to-take-a-screenshot-in-html-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

So the answer turned out to be by using scene.canvas.
I was directed to this solution by a [similar question](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/cesium-dev&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&hideforumtitle=true&fragments=true&parenturl=http%3A%2F%2Fcesiumjs.org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com%2Fforum%2F#!topic/cesium-dev/FdQk03zgOMI) on the Cesium Forum.